# Display Excel inside VB6 / VB.NET Form & work with Excel without excel menu

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, vb6

I have an Excel sheet with Macros enabled. I want to display the Excel sheet inside a VB6/VB.NET form without excel menu header and perform excel activities inside the form.

Please note that I need to perform some macros actions when some cell is entered...

**My Objective** is to create a standalone VB6/VB.Net Form in which excel cells should be displayed for performing marco actions.

I have tried searching for any sample but no luck. It should be something like this...
[image]

Can any one hint me to achieve this ?

Comment: if you accept the fact that it's not possible in VB6 standalone application and decide to use VBA check out [**this link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406319/display-a-part-of-an-excel-sheet-on-a-userform-using-vba/17407415#17407415)  :)

Comment: @mehow : Thanks for the link :) is it possible to make the VBA form  standalone ?

Comment: no it's not. VBA is integrated into Office and needs VBE environment to run. Why wont you use an external library to achieve display part of an excel on userform in VB6?

Comment: @mehow : could you please tell me what do you mean by external library here ?

Comment: @mehow : your linked answer is nice :) will it work in a system where Microsoft Office Spreadsheet 11.0 contol is not installed ? because I will add this in my pc and share it to all users

Comment: logan, it should work in any pc as the ActiveX will be already added to the assembly on the developing machine. Create one and send it over to a mate's machine and see yourself

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell - this is not possible. The reason being that you cannot subclass the excel window in VBA. 
If you program outside of excel with VB.NET or VB6 it would be sort of possible, but would probably not work really good.
If you only want to display some data from a sheet and perform some small actions on them, you could probably read the Data via the EPPLUS Library, display them as a datatable (EPPLUS can convert between datatable and excel files), perform your actions and save them to the file afterwards. But this would only work in VB.net

Comment: i want it in VB6 only. why I want is, i need to perform some macros when some cell is entered...

Comment: VB6 is no longer supported, so you should port it to something newer. If you want to run macros, you can do it easily with VBA in excel, without needing to embed excel somewhere. Google for VBA and events.

Comment: My Objective is to create a standalone VB6/VB.Net Form in which excel cells should be displayed for performing marco actions (question altered for more clarity)

Comment: @logan that's not possible unless you write your own library with graphical interface simulating excel's spreadsheet.

Comment: Won't work. Sometimes you should accept that answer and look for alternative workable solutions, sorry.

Comment: I agree with @ChristianSauer

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research into this last year.  There is no available package to do what you are asking that is provided by MS or for free, however, you could create a datagridview (DGV) in vb.net and load the data into the DGV via ADO.NET. The data loaded into the cells will mirror your spreadsheet. Then when you modify the cells in the DGV, have a label as you have shown to update the data changes back to the excel sheet.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a1c828d-04ed-4a8d-927d-3649f29d2060/import-data-from-excel-sheet-into-datagridview

As far as calling the macro, use the excel interop feature to call a macro:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2e33b8e5-c9fd-42a1-8d67-3d61d2cedc1c/how-to-call-excel-macros-programmatically-in-c

There may be some third party support for what you are doing, but of course it costs money:
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SpreadStudio/?gclid=CLKIy6TqwLkCFYZlOgodhToAZg

Comment: @logan You would have to handle the formatting in DGV yourself as ADO.net will only pull the data.

I suppose however, you could use interop.excel to loop sheet data/read cell styles and then try to translate that into the DGV

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx